# Display images from folder

Tags: php, css

I have been making a blog, but I have a problem. I can't display image from folders images. I need to display one image every time when name and comment put on the page. Every time another image and need to stay on page.
[Here is link](http://slimhamdi.net/lina/demos/blog-post-dark.html?name=hhhhhhh&email=hh%40hotmail.com&comment=h&send=)

```
http://slimhamdi.net/lina/demos/blog-post-dark.html?name=hhhhhhh&email=hh%40hotmail.com&comment=h&send=
```

I need same like this blog, I would like to avoid MySQL. Any help will be appreciated.

```
<?php 
$images = array("user1.jpg", "user2.jpg", "user1.jpg");
$images = glob('images/*'); 
shuffle($images );
foreach($images  as $image ) {     
break;     
 }  
 ?>
<img src="<?php echo "$image"; ?>" />
```

Answer (score 0):

why do you use break in foreach?
you should echo the img tag in foreach
if your images are in images folder, you shouldn't you glob, and instead you can concat it to path.

```
<?php 
  $images = array("user1.jpg", "user2.jpg", "user1.jpg");
  shuffle($images);
  foreach($images  as $image ) {     
    echo "<img src='images/{$image}' />";
   }  
  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting variables:

```
<?php
$images = array("user1.jpg", "user2.jpg", "user1.jpg");
$images = glob('images/*'); // Overwrites the previous $images
```

That way the `$images` in the `foreach` is something else.

There is also no need to use a `break` in the `foreach` loop

```
<?php 
$images = array("user1.jpg", "user2.jpg", "user1.jpg");
shuffle($images );
foreach($images  as $image ) {     
     echo '<img src="'.$image.'" />';
     //echo '<img src="images/'.$image.'">';// With file path
}
```